# How to use offline Visual Studio Community 2015 with expiration date

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have downloaded the Visual Studio Community 2015 (free version).

I can´t use it because the licence expired but I don't have Internet connection.

I have tried to search in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn950037.aspx but I couldn´t find what I need.

Is possible use it without Internet connection? How can I update the license without Internet connection?

Please Help! Don't vote negative if you dont leave a comment or really don´t know. **Not all of us have the knowledge.**

Comment: @KenWhite thank you for leaving your comment. I just only recived negatives votes without explanation.

Comment: @KenWhite However, no one has answered me, for example, that it is not possible because of licensing issues or something. They only leave negative feedback as if we all had knowledge .... By the way I explained my question very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible use it without internet connection if you have community version of Visual Studio and also you don't have key serial. Try to connect your pc to the internet once, then update the license and use Visual Studio offline by a short period. But it is totally necessary have internet in this case.

Comment: Here is a more or less official answer: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/9563619-enable-vs-community-activation-registration-offlin  As far as I know, the same policy applies to VS Community 2017.

Comment: @michael Burr thank you so much. I appreciate your feedback. Now I learned that in this case the Professional and Enterprise editions might be a better choice.... And according with my case (VS community) the license works for a period of 30 days. Thanks for sharing knowledge.